# Opening activity after clicking push notification android

Tags: android, push-notification

I am a huge noob to Android programming so sorry if this is a simple task. I pretty much followed the Vogella push notification tutorial for push notifications (http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html). I've read some other stack overflow questions but I'm a little confused on how to open a intent once I receive the notification.

For example, if I just wanted the notification to lead me to a website, how would that work? Would it have to go under my MessageReceivedActivity or another project/class all together?

Thanks

Here is the code I have for my C2DMMessageReceiver

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Log.w("C2DM", "Message Receiver called");
    if ("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE".equals(action)) {
        Log.w("C2DM", "Received message");
        final String payload = intent.getStringExtra("payload");
        Log.d("C2DM", "dmControl: payload = " + payload);
        // TODO Send this to my application server to get the real data
        // Lets make something visible to show that we received the message
        createNotification(context, payload);

    }
}

public void createNotification(Context context, String payload) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            "Message received", System.currentTimeMillis());
    // Hide the notification after its selected
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    //adding LED lights to notification
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MessageReceivedActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("payload", payload);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            intent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Message",
            "New message received", pendingIntent);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

}
```

}

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if you want to open a website on notification click try this:

```
    public void createNotification(Context context, String payload) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                "Message received", System.currentTimeMillis());
        // Hide the notification after its selected
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        //adding LED lights to notification
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;

        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", 
         Uri.parse("http://my.example.com/"));
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                intent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Message",
                "New message received", pendingIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

    }
```

Comment: When I do this, after clicking my push notification, I only see the message "New message received". Maybe something needs to tell the pendingIntent to open the intent?

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out through your code. Only had to change 1 little thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your base receiver for c2dm or the class the that extentd base reciever you have a handleMessage()::

Below is the sample code for handle message which launches the activity::

```
@Override
    protected void handleMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String regId = C2DMessaging.getRegistrationId(context);
        String logKey = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
        String title="";
        String message="";
        if (regId!= null) {
            if (intent.hasExtra(Constants.TITLE)) {
                title = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.TITLE);
            }
            if(intent.hasExtra(Constants.MESSAGE)){
                message = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.MESSAGE);
            }
            // TODO Send this to my application server to get the real data
            // Lets make something visible to show that we received the message
            if(!title.equals("") && !message.equals(""))
                createNotificationForMsg(context,title,message);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void createNotificationForMsg(Context context,String title,String message) {
        final String logKey = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

        try {
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
                    "update(s) received", System.currentTimeMillis());
            // Hide the notification after its selected
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            //adding sound to notification
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;            

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourAlertActivity.class);

                if(Constants.LOG)Log.d(logKey, Constants.TITLE +": "+ title +" , "+Constants.MESSAGE+": "+message);
                intent.putExtra(Constants.TITLE, title);
                intent.putExtra(Constants.MESSAGE, message);

                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MILLISECOND),  intent, android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Castrol",
                        title+"update Received", pendingIntent);
                notificationManager.notify(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MILLISECOND), notification);



        } catch (Exception e) {
//          MessageReceivedActivity.view.setText("createNotificationFor Msg: "
//                  + e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry but does base receiver mean Message Receiver or Registration Receiver? I assumed the activity would go under MessageReceivedActivity which extends Activity. But would it go under MessageReceiver which extends Broadcast Receiver?

Comment: I editted my question to include my code. So for example sake, let's say I want www.google.com to be opened upon clicking the notification? I understand how to do it with Intent, not sure how pendingIntent works