# Android Dialog with CountDown TImer

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, countdowntimer

In my app, I show the push notification as a Dialog that has two buttons named *Yes* and *No*. I need to  show a timer (20 seconds) running in the dialog's title.

If the user clicks *Yes*, it should go to an activity.
If the user clicks *No*, the dialog gets canceled before timer ends.
When the countdown finishes,the Dialog should disappear. How should I implement this?

Here is my Alert dialog Method

```
public void showAlertDialog(final Context context, String title, String message,
                            Boolean status) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);

    // Setting Icon to Dialog
    //alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.fail);

    // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    // Setting Negative "NO" Button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    //alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.counter);
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: have u geting puch notifecation on your app

Comment: create Receiver check puch notification come and open dialog in onreceive methed when puch notificatin come on device

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18307967/to-show-push-notification-content-into-the-alert-dialog-when-application-is-eith

Comment: Here I've completed the Dialog Part, the issue is running count down timer on that dialog

Comment: when dialog is open to timer and timertask

Comment: push notification comes, I get it and could show it as a Dialog, Here I need to set a Count Down Timer Running on the title part of the Dialog, When the Dialog Pops up the timer should start Automatically. Found some codes in stackoverflow those aren't fitting to my requirement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60524/discussion-between-naveen-tamrakar-and-user1799171).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend adding the countdown into the dialog's title. If you instead add it to the *No* button, it is more obvious for the user what will happen when the countdown finishes.

Here's code for an AlertDialog that does just that.

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Notification Title")
        .setMessage("Do you really want to delete the file?")
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO: Add positive button action code here
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
        .create();
dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
    private static final int AUTO_DISMISS_MILLIS = 6000;
    @Override
    public void onShow(final DialogInterface dialog) {
        final Button defaultButton = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
        final CharSequence negativeButtonText = defaultButton.getText();
        new CountDownTimer(AUTO_DISMISS_MILLIS, 100) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                defaultButton.setText(String.format(
                        Locale.getDefault(), "%s (%d)",
                        negativeButtonText,
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) + 1 //add one so it never displays zero
                ));
            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                if (((AlertDialog) dialog).isShowing()) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
});
dialog.show();
```

[image: dialog with countdown screenshot]

Comment: Quite nice solution; one addition - I believe, that you should remember timer var and cancel it on dialog dismiss.

Comment: Cleanest solution I've seen, and completely programmatic. Getting access to the button text was the crucial part. Wish I could upvote twice.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question I have prepared [a simple project at Github](https://github.com/afarber/android-questions/tree/master/DialogCountDown):

[image: screenshot]

Here is [my custom dialog class](https://github.com/afarber/android-questions/blob/master/DialogCountDown/app/src/main/java/de/afarber/dialogcountdown/MyDialog.java), which posts a runnable at the main thread handler and updates the text label on the "Cancel" button (the negative button) every second, until zero is reached:

```
public class MyDialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
    public final static String TAG = MyDialog.class.getName();
    private long mCountDown = 20L;
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            AlertDialog dialog = (AlertDialog) requireDialog();
            Button negativeButton = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
            negativeButton.setText(getString(R.string.dialog_cancel_button, mCountDown));
            if (--mCountDown <= 0) {
                dismiss();
            } else {
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000L);
            }
        }
    };

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity())
            .setTitle(R.string.dialog_title)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_ok_button, (dialogInterface, i) -> Log.d(TAG, "Ok clicked"))
            .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.dialog_cancel_button, mCountDown), null)
                .create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mRunnable.run();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
    }
}
```

As you see the class is quite simple. To launch the dialog just run:

```
MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), MyDialog.TAG);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Yes you can do it, the only thing you need to do is like this -->

`val dialogListener = DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which ->
                    when (which) {
                        BUTTON_POSITIVE -> {          
                        }
                        DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE -> {
                        }
                    }
                }
                val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle(“YOUR TITLE HERE”)
                    .setMessage(“YOUR MESSAGE HERE)
                    .setPositiveButton(“TEXT OF BUTTON”)
                    .setNegativeButton(“TEXT OF BUTTON”)
                    .create()
    
    dialog.setOnShowListener(object : OnShowListener {
                    private val AUTO_DISMISS_MILLIS =20000  //Timer in this case 20 Seconds
                    override fun onShow(dialog: DialogInterface) {
    //if you want to have stuff done by your buttons it's going go be here with a respective call like (dialog as AlertDialog).getButton(The button you want positive or negative) 
    then everything you want to happen on it 
    *************************************************
                        //here is the timer associated to the button 
                        val defaultButton: Button =
                            dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
                        val positiveButtonText: CharSequence = defaultButton.text
                        object : CountDownTimer(AUTO_DISMISS_MILLIS.toLong(), 100) {
                            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                                defaultButton.text = java.lang.String.format(
                                    Locale.getDefault(), "%s (%d)",
                                    positiveButtonText,
                                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) + 1
                                )
                            }
                            override fun onFinish() {
    //everything you wanna do on the moment the timer is off is going to happen here if you wanna open another dialog you need to call it here
                            }
                        }.start()
                    }
                })
                dialog.show()
            }
```